mapleader doesn't work AT ALL in lazyvim

Running :echo mapleader shows no message, but that can be because it's empty. But in this case it should default to \. So I try to use the command mapped to it, and it doesn't work.
I try to set vim.g.mapleader = "literally anything" in init.lua before loading lazy (otherwise I get an error). And echo mapleader still doesn't work. Trying to use it also doesn't work.

init.lua
vim.g.mapleader = "," -- or anything aelse
print("mapleader set to " .. vim.g.mapleader) -- this prints ,
require("config.lazy")

lua/config/keymaps.lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>", ":echo 'works!!'<CR>", { desc = "NeoTree focus" })


Turns out LazyVim was overriding the setting. I put the mapleader assignment into lua/config/options.lua and it started working.
The reason :echo mapleader wasn't printing anything is because it's a vim's command. For neovim I had to use :lua print(vim.inspect(vim.g.mapleader))

You're correct about LazyVim overriding it, but the reason why :echo mapleader prints nothing is not that it's a Vim vs NeoVim command, but it's that LazyVim sets it to "space" so it only prints a space. If you use :echo '['.mapleader.']' you'll see it will print [ ] with a space in between the brackets.
